# Loading Nested Objects GraphQL

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, graphql, hotchocolate

How do you load nested types? For example, I have fairly simple model that looks like:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public string OrderId { get; set; }
    
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
}
```

My query does the following (returns hardcoded data)

```
    [UseProjection]
    [UseFiltering]
    [UseSorting]
    public IQueryable<Customer> Customers()
    {
        var customers = new List<Customer>
        {
            new()
            {
                CustomerId = "1", Forename = "Foo", LastName = "Blah",
                Orders = _orderService.GetOrdersByCustomerId("")
            },
            new()
            {
                CustomerId = "2", Forename = "Bar", LastName = "BlahBlah",
                Orders = _orderService.GetOrdersByCustomerId("")
            }
        };
        
        return customers.AsQueryable();
    }
```

The `_orderService` its calling is returning hardcoded data:

```
    public ICollection<Order> GetOrdersByCustomerId(string customerId)
    {
        return new List<Order>
        {
            new() { OrderId = $"{customerId}-99", CustomerId = "1" },
            new() { OrderId = $"{customerId}-98", CustomerId = "2" }
        };
    }
```

My query works fine for the top level but doesn't seem to filter the nested types.

```
query {
  customers(where: { customerId: { eq: "1" } }) {
    forename
    lastName
    orders {
      orderId
    }
  }
}
```

I am clearly missing something or perhaps I misusing.

For my desired output I would need to change the query to be:

```
query {
  customers(where: { customerId: { eq: "1" } }) {
    forename
    lastName
    orders(where: { customerId: { eq: "1" } }) {
      orderId
      customerId
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case you do not need `UseProjection` since there is no database involved. Remove it and it should just work. `UseProjection` would rewrite the GraphQL query on top of the queryable to translate it to a native database query. If you put EF Core in for instance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you looking nested object filtering. This can be done like this:

```html
    public class CustomerType : ObjectType<Customer>
    {
        protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor<Customer> descriptor)
        {
            descriptor.Field(f => f.Orders).UseFiltering();
        }
    }
```